# cube.js join compile "error does not match any of the allowed types"

Tags: cube.js

I have 2 tables, one contains daily data and the other contains attributes that I would like to use for segmenting data.

I got the following Error when I try to compile my cube.js schema.

#### cube.js error

> Error: Error: Compile errors: DailyVolumes cube: "dimensions.wellId"
> does not match any of the allowed types Possible reasons (one of):    *
> (dimensions.wellId.case) is required  * (dimensions.wellId.sql = () =>
> `well_id`) is not allowed     * (dimensions.wellId.primary_key = true) is
> not allowed

#### The followings are my tables DDL and cube.js Schemas:

```
drop table if exists daily_volumes;
drop table if exists wells;

create table if not exists wells (
    id integer not null,
    well_name varchar(255),
    api_10 varchar(13),
    area varchar(255),
    run varchar(255),
    engineering_id varchar(50),
    accounting_id varchar(50),
    active_flag int,
    primary key (id)
);

create table if not exists daily_volumes(   
    well_id integer not null,
    record_date timestamp not null, 
    oil_prod_bbl float not null,
    water_prod_bbl float not null,
    gas_prod_mcf float not null,
    primary key (well_id, record_date),
    constraint fk_well_id foreign key (well_id) references wells(id)
);
```

#### schema/Wells.js

```js
cube(`Wells`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM public.wells`,
  
  preAggregations: {
    // Pre-Aggregations definitions go here
    // Learn more here: https://cube.dev/docs/caching/pre-aggregations/getting-started  
  },
  
  joins: {
    
  },
  
  measures: {
    count: {
      type: `count`,
      drillMembers: [id, wellName, engineeringId, accountingId]
    }
  },
  
  dimensions: {
    id: {
      sql: `id`,
      type: `number`,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    
    wellName: {
      sql: `well_name`,
      type: `string`
    },
    
    api10: {
      sql: `api_10`,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Api 10`
    },
    
    area: {
      sql: `area`,
      type: `string`
    },
    
    run: {
      sql: `run`,
      type: `string`
    },
    
    engineeringId: {
      sql: `engineering_id`,
      type: `string`
    },
    
    accountingId: {
      sql: `accounting_id`,
      type: `string`
    }
  },
  
  dataSource: `default`
});
```

#### schema/DailyVolumes.js

```js
cube(`DailyVolumes`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM public.daily_volumes`,

  preAggregations: {
    // Pre-Aggregations definitions go here
    // Learn more here: https://cube.dev/docs/caching/pre-aggregations/getting-started
  },

  joins: {
    Wells: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.well_id = ${Wells}.id`,
      relationship: `belongsTo`,
    },
  },

  measures: {
    count: {
      type: `count`,
      sql: `id`,
      // drillMembers: [recordDate],
    },
  },

  dimensions: {
    recordDate: {
      sql: `record_date`,
      type: `time`,
    },
    wellId: {
      sql: `well_id`,
      type: `number`,
      primary_key: true,
    },
  },

  dataSource: `default`,
});
```

Comment: i added `shown:true` to the primary key and now it works.  Not sure why but it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue was that you used `primary_key` (snake case) instead of `primaryKey` (camel case), as described in docs: https://cube.dev/docs/schema/reference/dimensions#primary-key

I also have to admit that the error message is not very helpful now.

Comment: I must have inadvertently fixed the snake case when pasting code from the docs, thanks for the help pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

> Setting primaryKey to true will change the default value of the shown
> parameter to false. If you still want shown to be true — set it
> manually.

Extracted from [Documentation Page](https://cube.dev/docs/schema/reference/joins#setting-a-primary-key).